# Show all widgets as big as possible

Tags: c++, linux, user-interface, gtkmm

I am writing an Application with Gtkmm in C++. At some point, the Application will show live footage of some cameras. They are drawn on a `Gtk::DrawingArea`, so we can treat everything for the question as a `Gtk::DrawingArea`.

I have something between 3 and 9 cameras. I want all cameras to always be on the screen as big as possible organized in a grid and all camera images shall be of the same size.

Is there a way to achive this with existing Widgets or do I have to implement some dark-gtk-magic? I thought maybe about something like `Gtk::FlowBox` but I cannot find any informations on this kind of issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just answered a question about [filling a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49089488/6045183), maybe this is what you are looking for to apply to your `Gtk::DrawingArea`.

You may also be interested in this methods for the grid:

- [set_row_homogeneous(bool homogeneous = true)](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Grid.html#ad2587a5431a9fb864db8d6da21bb6844)
- [set_column_homogeneous(bool homogeneous = true)](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Grid.html#a58ea6e69a33a9e719f5b5b4b430e8de3)

Comment: Yep.  Easiest way to do this.  Now if you had a dynamically growing grid, this might not work.